# Android, Chrome, and simulating clicks to start Intent

Tags: android, google-chrome, android-intent, anchor, simulate

Running website with Chrome on android tablet. Need to launch intent from intent anchor within chrome.

Works fine when done like this:

a `href='myscheme://mypackage.com' onclick='javascript:gotonextpagefunction();'`

So if that is clicked it works, as mentioned. But I need to have the click simulated, for various reasons. So I found various methods to do that, such as:

```
document.getElementById('myanchor').click();
```

That will open the APK, but then the browser closes. I've read that a gesture is required, but the fact that the APK actually starts makes me think I just need to adjust the javascript in some way. Tried **jquery** too.

Any help is appreciated.